# Problems to load own font in mPDF

Tags: php, fonts, mpdf

I know that question is is asked not the first time but all the other threads havn't helped me to get it work.
I trie to get my own font work in my mPDF call.
In read that version 7 I can load my own font without changing the config_fonts.php. Here is my try:

```
$mpdf = new \mPDF('utf-8','A4','');

$mpdf->fontDir = './assets/fonts/';
$mpdf->fontdata = array(
    "qanela" => array(
        'R' => "QanelasSoft-Regular.ttf",
        'B' => "QanelasSoft-Bold.ttf",
    ),
);

$mpdf->SetFont('qanela');
```

with this code I get the errormessage

> mPDF Error - Font is not supported - dejavusanscondensed.

it is called from

> mpdf/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/mpdf.php

on Line 3809 with

> if (!isset($this->fontdata[$family][$stylekey]) || !$this->fontdata[$family][$stylekey]) {
>               throw new MpdfException('mPDF Error - Font is not supported - ' . $family . ' ' . $style);
>           }

Hopefull someone can help me.

Cheers

Comment: I don't see the relation between your code and the error, which is about a completely other font?

Comment: Hi, I don't know. I don't use the dejavusanscondensed anywhere.
I think this error comes from my array where I load my new font.

Comment: I think DejaVu is the standard font, it should always be there.

Comment: I copied the DejaVu Font in my own font folder but it changed nothing on the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code sample is somehow weird:

- To be able to use `fontDir` property, you must use mPDF 7.x
- Your creation of mpdf instance `new \mPDF` suggests 6.x - 7.x has a namespaced signature `new \Mpdf\Mpdf()`
- In 6.x you can set your own font dir via setting `_MPDF_SYSTEM_TTFONTS` constant:

`define('_MPDF_SYSTEM_TTFONTS', './assets/fonts/');`

---

> In read that version 7 I can load my own font without changing the config_fonts.php

There is no config_fonts.php file in v 7. All changes to configuration can be done in constructor `$config` parameter or by altering fontdata property of mPDF instance after creation of the object - as you are trying to do. See below.

---

Also, try to append your font settings to the fontData property instead of overriding its contents:

```
$mpdf->fontdata['qanela'] = 
    array(
        'R' => "QanelasSoft-Regular.ttf",
        'B' => "QanelasSoft-Bold.ttf",
    );
```

Comment: Hi, thanks your are right I use version 6.1. I thought the hole time I use v 7.
But that it is also in Beta explains also why the documentation stops at version 6.

Comment: Documentation for 7.x is being prepared in `development` branch of its github repo https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf.github.io. Not too comfortable, but the information can be found there.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to override the entire `fontdata` array (which is what you are doing). Instead, add your new record on the end of it.

```
$mpdf->fontdata['qanelasSof'] = array(
    'R' => "QanelasSoft-Regular.ttf",
    'B' => "QanelasSoft-Bold.ttf",
);
```

Then ensure your TTF font files are stored in the ttfonts directory.

Answer (score 1):

mPDF 7.x does not support uppercase fonts. In such of situation, you must rename your font name to lowercase

```
$mpdf->fontdata = array(
    "qanela" => array(
        'R' => "qanelassoftregular.ttf",
        'B' => "qanelassoftbold.ttf",
    ),
)
```